# Error compiling arduino sketch to seeduino xiao for RF24 Module

Tags: arduino-nano, library, compile, error

I am trying to get 2 rf24 modules talking to each other. This is my first real arduino project so bear with my ignorance please.  I could get them to work with 2 arduino nano but, when trying to upload the same sketch to a seeduino xiao it won't compile. Not sure how to format this better (please intstruct) sorry<-- Here is a copy of the error message:

```
Arduino: 1.8.19 (Windows Store 1.8.57.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Seeeduino XIAO, Arduino, On"

In file included from C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:9:0:

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/adc.h:684:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __I  ADC_STATUS_Type           STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x19 (R/   8) Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/dac.h:277:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __I  DAC_STATUS_Type           STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x7 (R/   8) Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/eic.h:667:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __I  EIC_STATUS_Type           STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x01 (R/   8) Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:26:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define CONFIG      0x00

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/eic.h:675:34: note: in expansion of macro 'CONFIG'

   __IO EIC_CONFIG_Type           CONFIG[2];   /**< \brief Offset: 0x18 (R/W 32) Configuration n */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/gclk.h:301:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __I  GCLK_STATUS_Type          STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x1 (R/   8) Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/nvmctrl.h:346:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __IO NVMCTRL_STATUS_Type       STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x18 (R/W 16) Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/rtc.h:1000:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __IO RTC_STATUS_Type           STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x0A (R/W  8) Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/rtc.h:1020:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __IO RTC_STATUS_Type           STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x0A (R/W  8) Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/rtc.h:1042:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __IO RTC_STATUS_Type           STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x0A (R/W  8) Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/sercom.h:1419:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __IO SERCOM_I2CM_STATUS_Type   STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x1A (R/W 16) I2CM Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/sercom.h:1441:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __IO SERCOM_I2CS_STATUS_Type   STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x1A (R/W 16) I2CS Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/sercom.h:1463:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __IO SERCOM_SPI_STATUS_Type    STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x1A (R/W 16) SPI Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/sercom.h:1488:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __IO SERCOM_USART_STATUS_Type  STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x1A (R/W 16) USART Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/tc.h:621:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __I  TC_STATUS_Type            STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x0F (R/   8) Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/tc.h:645:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __I  TC_STATUS_Type            STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x0F (R/   8) Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/tc.h:667:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __I  TC_STATUS_Type            STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x0F (R/   8) Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/tcc.h:253:14: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

     uint32_t STATUS:1;         /*!< bit:      3  Status Busy                        */

              ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/tcc.h:1799:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __IO TCC_STATUS_Type           STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x30 (R/W 32) Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/usb.h:1728:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __I  USB_DEVICE_STATUS_Type    STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x00C (R/   8) DEVICE Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/usb.h:1759:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __IO USB_HOST_STATUS_Type      STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x00C (R/W  8) HOST Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:26:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define CONFIG      0x00

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/wdt.h:290:34: note: in expansion of macro 'CONFIG'

   __IO WDT_CONFIG_Type           CONFIG;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x1 (R/W  8) Configuration */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\nRF24L01.h:33:21: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define STATUS      0x07

                     ^

C:\Users\User\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\Seeeduino\tools\CMSIS-Atmel\1.2.1/CMSIS-Atmel/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/samd21/include/component/wdt.h:296:34: note: in expansion of macro 'STATUS'

   __I  WDT_STATUS_Type           STATUS;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x7 (R/   8) Status */

                                  ^~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::print_status(uint8_t)':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:188:22: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

            (status & _BV(RX_DR))?1:0,

                      ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:188:22: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

            (status & _BV(RX_DR))?1:0,

                      ^~~

                      _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:186:3: error: 'printf_P' was not declared in this scope

   printf_P(PSTR("STATUS\t\t = 0x%02x RX_DR=%x TX_DS=%x MAX_RT=%x RX_P_NO=%x TX_FULL=%x\r\n"),

   ^~~~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:186:3: note: suggested alternative: 'sprintf_P'

   printf_P(PSTR("STATUS\t\t = 0x%02x RX_DR=%x TX_DS=%x MAX_RT=%x RX_P_NO=%x TX_FULL=%x\r\n"),

   ^~~~~~~~

   sprintf_P

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::print_observe_tx(uint8_t)':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:200:3: error: 'printf_P' was not declared in this scope

   printf_P(PSTR("OBSERVE_TX=%02x: POLS_CNT=%x ARC_CNT=%x\r\n"),

   ^~~~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:200:3: note: suggested alternative: 'sprintf_P'

   printf_P(PSTR("OBSERVE_TX=%02x: POLS_CNT=%x ARC_CNT=%x\r\n"),

   ^~~~~~~~

   sprintf_P

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::print_byte_register(const char*, uint8_t, uint8_t)':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:212:3: error: 'printf_P' was not declared in this scope

   printf_P(PSTR(PRIPSTR"\t%c ="),name,extra_tab);

   ^~~~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:212:3: note: suggested alternative: 'sprintf_P'

   printf_P(PSTR(PRIPSTR"\t%c ="),name,extra_tab);

   ^~~~~~~~

   sprintf_P

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::print_address_register(const char*, uint8_t, uint8_t)':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:223:3: error: 'printf_P' was not declared in this scope

   printf_P(PSTR(PRIPSTR"\t%c ="),name,extra_tab);

   ^~~~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:223:3: note: suggested alternative: 'sprintf_P'

   printf_P(PSTR(PRIPSTR"\t%c ="),name,extra_tab);

   ^~~~~~~~

   sprintf_P

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::printDetails()':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:325:3: error: 'printf_P' was not declared in this scope

   printf_P(PSTR("Data Rate\t = %S\r\n"),pgm_read_word(&rf24_datarate_e_str_P[getDataRate()]));

   ^~~~~~~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:325:3: note: suggested alternative: 'sprintf_P'

   printf_P(PSTR("Data Rate\t = %S\r\n"),pgm_read_word(&rf24_datarate_e_str_P[getDataRate()]));

   ^~~~~~~~

   sprintf_P

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::begin()':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:382:25: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   write_register(STATUS,_BV(RX_DR) | _BV(TX_DS) | _BV(MAX_RT) );

                         ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:382:25: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   write_register(STATUS,_BV(RX_DR) | _BV(TX_DS) | _BV(MAX_RT) );

                         ^~~

                         _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::startListening()':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:398:50: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   write_register(CONFIG, read_register(CONFIG) | _BV(PWR_UP) | _BV(PRIM_RX));

                                                  ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:398:50: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   write_register(CONFIG, read_register(CONFIG) | _BV(PWR_UP) | _BV(PRIM_RX));

                                                  ^~~

                                                  _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::powerDown()':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:429:50: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   write_register(CONFIG,read_register(CONFIG) & ~_BV(PWR_UP));

                                                  ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:429:50: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   write_register(CONFIG,read_register(CONFIG) & ~_BV(PWR_UP));

                                                  ^~~

                                                  _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::powerUp()':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:436:49: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   write_register(CONFIG,read_register(CONFIG) | _BV(PWR_UP));

                                                 ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:436:49: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   write_register(CONFIG,read_register(CONFIG) | _BV(PWR_UP));

                                                 ^~~

                                                 _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'bool RF24::write(const void*, uint8_t)':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:468:25: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   while( ! ( status & ( _BV(TX_DS) | _BV(MAX_RT) ) ) && ( millis() - sent_at < timeout ) );

                         ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:468:25: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   while( ! ( status & ( _BV(TX_DS) | _BV(MAX_RT) ) ) && ( millis() - sent_at < timeout ) );

                         ^~~

                         _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::startWrite(const void*, uint8_t)':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:510:52: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   write_register(CONFIG, ( read_register(CONFIG) | _BV(PWR_UP) ) & ~_BV(PRIM_RX) );

                                                    ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:510:52: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   write_register(CONFIG, ( read_register(CONFIG) | _BV(PWR_UP) ) & ~_BV(PRIM_RX) );

                                                    ^~~

                                                    _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'bool RF24::available(uint8_t*)':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:552:28: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   bool result = ( status & _BV(RX_DR) );

                            ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:552:28: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   bool result = ( status & _BV(RX_DR) );

                            ^~~

                            _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'bool RF24::read(void*, uint8_t)':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:585:39: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   return read_register(FIFO_STATUS) & _BV(RX_EMPTY);

                                       ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:585:39: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   return read_register(FIFO_STATUS) & _BV(RX_EMPTY);

                                       ^~~

                                       _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::whatHappened(bool&, bool&, bool&)':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:594:42: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   uint8_t status = write_register(STATUS,_BV(RX_DR) | _BV(TX_DS) | _BV(MAX_RT) );

                                          ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:594:42: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   uint8_t status = write_register(STATUS,_BV(RX_DR) | _BV(TX_DS) | _BV(MAX_RT) );

                                          ^~~

                                          _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::openReadingPipe(uint8_t, uint64_t)':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:652:57: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

     write_register(EN_RXADDR,read_register(EN_RXADDR) | _BV(pgm_read_byte(&child_pipe_enable[child])));

                                                         ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:652:57: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

     write_register(EN_RXADDR,read_register(EN_RXADDR) | _BV(pgm_read_byte(&child_pipe_enable[child])));

                                                         ^~~

                                                         _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::enableDynamicPayloads()':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:671:51: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   write_register(FEATURE,read_register(FEATURE) | _BV(EN_DPL) );

                                                   ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:671:51: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   write_register(FEATURE,read_register(FEATURE) | _BV(EN_DPL) );

                                                   ^~~

                                                   _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::enableAckPayload()':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:700:51: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   write_register(FEATURE,read_register(FEATURE) | _BV(EN_ACK_PAY) | _BV(EN_DPL) );

                                                   ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:700:51: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   write_register(FEATURE,read_register(FEATURE) | _BV(EN_ACK_PAY) | _BV(EN_DPL) );

                                                   ^~~

                                                   _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::setAutoAck(uint8_t, bool)':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:770:16: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

       en_aa |= _BV(pipe) ;

                ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:770:16: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

       en_aa |= _BV(pipe) ;

                ^~~

                _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:774:17: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

       en_aa &= ~_BV(pipe) ;

                 ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:774:17: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

       en_aa &= ~_BV(pipe) ;

                 ^~~

                 _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::setPALevel(rf24_pa_dbm_e)':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:799:14: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   setup &= ~(_BV(RF_PWR_LOW) | _BV(RF_PWR_HIGH)) ;

              ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:799:14: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   setup &= ~(_BV(RF_PWR_LOW) | _BV(RF_PWR_HIGH)) ;

              ^~~

              _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'rf24_pa_dbm_e RF24::getPALevel()':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:832:46: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   uint8_t power = read_register(RF_SETUP) & (_BV(RF_PWR_LOW) | _BV(RF_PWR_HIGH)) ;

                                              ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:832:46: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   uint8_t power = read_register(RF_SETUP) & (_BV(RF_PWR_LOW) | _BV(RF_PWR_HIGH)) ;

                                              ^~~

                                              _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'bool RF24::setDataRate(rf24_datarate_e)':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:864:14: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   setup &= ~(_BV(RF_DR_LOW) | _BV(RF_DR_HIGH)) ;

              ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:864:14: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   setup &= ~(_BV(RF_DR_LOW) | _BV(RF_DR_HIGH)) ;

              ^~~

              _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'rf24_datarate_e RF24::getDataRate()':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:907:43: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   uint8_t dr = read_register(RF_SETUP) & (_BV(RF_DR_LOW) | _BV(RF_DR_HIGH));

                                           ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:907:43: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   uint8_t dr = read_register(RF_SETUP) & (_BV(RF_DR_LOW) | _BV(RF_DR_HIGH));

                                           ^~~

                                           _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::setCRCLength(rf24_crclength_e)':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:933:47: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   uint8_t config = read_register(CONFIG) & ~( _BV(CRCO) | _BV(EN_CRC)) ;

                                               ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:933:47: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   uint8_t config = read_register(CONFIG) & ~( _BV(CRCO) | _BV(EN_CRC)) ;

                                               ^~~

                                               _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'rf24_crclength_e RF24::getCRCLength()':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:957:46: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   uint8_t config = read_register(CONFIG) & ( _BV(CRCO) | _BV(EN_CRC)) ;

                                              ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:957:46: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   uint8_t config = read_register(CONFIG) & ( _BV(CRCO) | _BV(EN_CRC)) ;

                                              ^~~

                                              _B

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp: In member function 'void RF24::disableCRC()':

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:974:46: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

   uint8_t disable = read_register(CONFIG) & ~_BV(EN_CRC) ;

                                              ^~~

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master\RF24.cpp:974:46: note: suggested alternative: '_B'

   uint8_t disable = read_register(CONFIG) & ~_BV(EN_CRC) ;

                                              ^~~

                                              _B

Multiple libraries were found for "nRF24L01.h"

 Used: C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24-master

 Not used: C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\NRFLite

exit status 1

Error compiling for board Seeeduino XIAO.



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

I suspect I have multiple problems as it took a lot of playing around with the libraries to get the RF24-Master library to work. I may have messed that up somehow (but it was working with the Nano...so...??).

Here is a copy of the sketch being loaded:

[code]

#include <SPI.h>
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"

int DataMgs[1];
RF24 radio(9,10);
const uint64_t pipe = 0xE14BC8F482LL;
int Relay1 = 5;

void setup()
{
pinMode(Relay1, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(57600);
radio.begin();
radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipe);
radio.startListening();
}

void loop()
{
if (radio.available())
{
bool done = false;
while (!done)
{
done = radio.read(DataMgs, 1);
Serial.print("NRF24L01 Receiver: ");
Serial.println(DataMgs[0]);

```
  if (DataMgs[0] == 1)
  {
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(Relay1, HIGH);
  }

  if (DataMgs[0] == 2)
  {
    delay(10);digitalWrite(Relay1, LOW);
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

}
else
{
Serial.println("Waiting for signal...");
}
}
[/code]

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

P.S. If anyone can guide me through this issue I can send some crypto your way- thanks again.